# Custom control resize C#

Tags: c#, winforms, resize, custom-controls

I would like to resize custom control according to items it content
This dont work for me:

```
public CustomControl()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    if (ErrorLimits == false && Range == false)
    {
        this.Size = new Size(100, 100);
        this.Invalidate();
    }
    else
    {
        this.Size = new Size(250,250);
        this.Invalidate();
    }

}
```

It changing nothing, How can I achieve it? 
Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure you haven't set Dock/Anchor properties?

Comment: I would like to change size in this custom control automaticaly inside custom control, not outside in another form to change my custom control

Comment: I guess what Kshitij meant is that the docking/anchoring would override values set by assigning the value to the Size property.

Answer (score 3):

The containing form will instantiate `CustomControl` and then set its properties in the form's `InitializeComponent` function. The property values set in the form's designer are applied *after* the constructor to `CustomControl` has finished (which, if you think about it, they'd have to be).

Since you are setting your custom sizes in the control's constructor, they're probably getting overridden by the designer values immediately afterwards before the form is displayed.

A better place to set the size is the [`UserControl.Load`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.usercontrol.load.aspx) event, which occurs after the designer properties have been set.

An even better option would be to properly support [auto sizing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171729.aspx).